# How to run a QT application on boot in yocto

Tags: linux, qt, yocto

So I have added local qt project files to my Yocto image and have compiled it by creating a custom recipe file and inheriting qmake5. Now I want to execute this application at boot. I know how to execute a simple .c application using systemd services however I am confused about how to use this approach to launch a qt application since it contains multiple files. How can I make systemd service which launches my qt application and which files are to to be called in this service?

Comment: What platform you are using? `wayland` or other ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not trying to use wayland or x11 server. I am trying to use eglfs plugin and alongside systemd service to try running my QT application on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Please compile your application, add it to your image and then use a system service like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Your Qt Application
After=other.service # Specify other required services for your Qt appe.g. network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCE888=1
Environment=QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs
Environment=QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCEVSYNC=1
Environment=QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/qt5/plugins
Environment=QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=eglfs_viv
Environment=QT_QPA_EGLFS_FB=/dev/fbX    # fbX - your framebuffer number
ExecStart=/directory/your_qt_app
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall your_qt_app
StandardOutput=journal
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```